# Kleene's three-valued logic and tautology

Tags: logic, computer-science

I am working on a knowledgebase system as a hobby project, and I would like to incorporate some mechanisms for logic reasoning under uncertainty. I have looked into [Kleene's three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), but I am puzzled by the (well known) problem with tautology/contradiction.

Denote the truth values by $\top$ (true), $\bot$ (false), and $?$ (unknown). The problem is that, because $\neg\ ?\ =\ ?$, the formulas $p \lor \neg p$ and $p \land \neg p$ are no longer a tautology/contradiction: if $p =\ ?$, then the truth tables give $\ ?\ \lor \neg\ ?\ =\ ?\ \lor\ ? =\ ?$, and similarly, $\ ?\ \land \neg\ ? =\ ?$ . But intuition suggests that even though we don't know the truth value of $p$, we should still have $p \lor \neg p = \top$ and $p \land \neg p = \bot\ $, as with boolean logic.

I think this is because truth tables don't recognize the difference between a conjuction or disjunction between (i) two *distinct* unknowns, and (ii) *one* unknown and its own inverse. In case (i), the result should indeed be unknown, as the truth tables indicate, but in case (ii) it should not, we should obtain $\ ?\ \lor \neg\ ?\ = \top$ and $\ ?\ \land \neg\ ?\ = \bot\ $. I have a feeling there is also some issue with treating $\ ?\ $ as a third truth value, while it actually means there is *no known* truth value, but this is not clear to me.

I feel there should be some way of treating tautology/contradiction in three-valued logic without causing logical inconsistencies, but I am not well versed in logic, and I can't really read research level logic papers, that stuff is just over my head.

Is there any known solution to this problem, for example in automated reasoning or knowledgebase systems? If so, I would very much appreciate an intuitive (rather than super formal) explanation.

Comment: Correct: $P \lor \lnot P$ is Unknown for $P$ Unknown. This is quite "natural": the *Law of Excluded Middle* will fail in a three-valued logic.

Comment: *Note* : in classical two valued-logic, $p \land \lnot p$ is **not** a *tautology*, but a *contradiction*.

Comment: If we define a *tautology* in a three-valued logical system to be a formula that always has the value **T**, we have that there are no tautologies nor contradictions in Kleene's three-valued logic.

Comment: The "relevant" concept is that of *quasi-tautology* : a formula that is never false. The set of *quasi-tautologies* of Kleene's 3-val logic is exactly the set of classical tautologies.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  To me it seems rather *unnatural* that $p \lor \neg p$ is unknown.  It is true regardless of whether $p$ is true or false, so it should still be true when $p$ is unknown. We do not need to know $p$ to determine the truth value of the formula.  Similarly, $p \land \neg p$ should always be false (yes you're right, should be called contradiction). What am I missing?

Comment: But it follows from the 3-val truth-tables ... If $P$ is Unk also $\lnot P$ is Unk. And $P \lor Q$ is Unk when both $P$ and $Q$ are.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA,  Yes, that it the problem --- I think the truth tables are not the whole story here.  I looks like Casper's answer is what I was looking for, but have to think about is a little ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the notion of *supervaluation*. Let $P$ be the set of atomic propositions. Then a valuation is any function from $P$ to $\{\top,\bot,?\}$. A valuation $\overline v$ is a complete extension of an evaluation $v$ if for all $p\in P$ it is the case that

- $v(p)=\top$ implies $\overline v(p)=\top$,
- $v(p)=\bot$ implies $\overline v(p)=\bot$, and
- $v(p)=\mathord ?$ implies $\overline v(p)=\top$ or $\overline v(p)=\bot$.

(Intuitively, a complete extension $\overline v$ is a way the world can be that is consistent with the information contained in $v$.)

Given a valuation $v$, a sentence $\phi$ is supervaluation-true if $\phi$ is classically true under all complete extensions of $v$, and similarly for supervaluation-false.

Take the sentence $p\vee\neg p$ as example when the truth value of $p$ is unknown, i.e. $v(p)=\mathord ?$. Any complete extension $\overline v$ of $v$ will have $\overline v(p)=\top$ or $\overline v(p)=\bot$. In both cases $p\vee\neg p$ is classically true. Hence, $p\vee\neg p$ is supervaluation-true in this case. Of course, $p\vee\neg p$ is also supervaluation-true if $v(p)=\top$ or $v(p)=\bot$, so $p\vee\neg p$ always comes out supervaluation-true, as desired.

Comment: Thanks, this does sound like what I need! Do you know if there is any knowledgebase / reasoning system / logic programming language that implements this?

Comment: @Roland: No, I don't know that. All I know is that the idea originates with van Fraassen (Singular terms, truth-value gaps, and free logic. The Journal of Philosophy 63 (1966), 481-495), and has been used in connection with sentences that have been argued to *be* neither true nor false, such as 'The present king of France is wise' and 'This sentence is false'.